# Changing the code language with preserved history in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I am about to convert a Delphi-project to C# and I wonder how I should handle it in Team Foundation Server? I have put in the legacy code in TFS and have now run the code through Delphi2CS. How should I put the new generated C# code in TFS so that you can follow the history from Delphi code to C# code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a one-to-one *file* level correspondence between the Delphi and C#, you could arrange for each change to be a rename-and-edit, taking `Example.pas` to `Example.cs` and so on.

I'm not sure how useful this would be though - you might well be better off putting the C# translation in a separate, new, place and merely keeping the Delphi around for reference.